# Scalar function-Merge

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a scalar function which is written 3 times with a minor change. I m planning to merge those three functions into one function.

```
ForStudent- A
Declare @CN INT
SELECT @cn=COUNT(*)
FROM XYZ A
WHERE A.subjects in ('1223','2234','3345')

IF @cnt>3       
SELECT @Pass=1      
ELSE       
SELECT @Pass=0 

RETURN @Pass
END




//Similarly ForStudent - B
     Declare @CN INT
        SELECT @cn=COUNT(*)
        FROM XYZ A
        WHERE A.subjects in ('1214','0987','0098')

        IF @cnt>5      
        SELECT @Pass=1      
        ELSE       
        SELECT @Pass=0 

        RETURN @Pass
        END
```

Same for student 3.

For instance there are only 3 students (fixed value=3), and they have the fixed sujects. How can i merge these three functions into one?

```
I am presently doing with
IF @Student= 'A'
BEGIN
Call the code for A
END
IF @Student = 'B'
BEGIN
Call the code for B
END
IF @Student = 'C'
Call the code for C
END
```

Is there any better solution can anyone think of?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do it is to have a `StudentSubjects` table (possibly with some indication that it's for use with this function, or using an existing such table where the 3 special subjects can be marked in some way)

```
CREATE TABLE StudentSubjects (
    StudentID char(1) not null,
    Subject char(4) not null
)
```

(You'll have 3 rows for each student, with each subject stored separately)

And then your function will just be:

```
SELECT @cn=COUNT(*)
FROM XYZ A
WHERE A.subjects in (select Subject from StudentSubjects where StudentID=@StudentID)
```